# White pages on Frontend

Tags: craft-pro

I'm quite new to Craft. I was working on templates, then I logged in to create a new section and now any frontend route is returning a blank page.
500 Internal Server Error.

I restarted, Nginx, reboot Ubuntu server, etc.

Control Panel is working fine, I haven't touched any configuration file that I'm aware of.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error with Twig templates.

In case anyone is interested, I was using `extends` in a template that was `include` by a index template. Generating a sort of bad recursion that emptied memory ( PHP Error ).